# Confusion about Sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Reading through Chapter 8 of Brezis. We see that $C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $W^{1,\,p}(I)$. Later on in the chapter we define $W^{1,\,p}_{0}(I)$ to be the closure of $C_{c}^{1}(I)$ in $W^{1,\,p}(I)$. This $W^{1,\,p}_{0}(I)$ space has really confused me.

1. What happens when look at $C_{c}^{\infty}(I)$ which causes us to lose density in $W^{1,\,p}(I)$?
2. This question is linked to the first question. Suppose $(u_{n})\in C_{c}^{1}(I)$, then $(u_{n}')\in C_{c}(I)$. Both $C_{c}^{1}(I)$ and $C_{c}(I)$ are dense in $L^{p}(I)$, so $u_{n}\rightarrow u$ and $u_{n}'\rightarrow g$ in $L^{p}(I)$. Hence why cannot we not say that $u_{n}\rightarrow u$ in $W^{1,\,p}$ by taking $u'=g$?
3. By definition $\overline{C_{c}^{1}(I)}=W^{1,\,p}_{0}(I)$ in the $W^{1,\,p}$ norm. So how does one show density of $C_{c}^{\infty}(I)$ in $W^{1,\,p}_{0}(I)$? Is it sufficient to show that $C_{c}^{\infty}(I)$ is dense in $C_{c}^{1}(I)$ with respect to the supremum norm?

Answer (score 1):

It's not true that $\mathcal C_c^\infty (I)$ is dense in $W^{1,p}(I)$ when $I\neq \mathbb R$. What is true is $\mathcal C_c^\infty (\mathbb R)$ is dense in $W^{1,p}(\mathbb R)$. And indeed, if $I\neq \mathbb R$ is an interval, we define $W_0^{1,p}(I)$ as the closure of $\mathcal C_c^\infty (I)$ in $W^{1,p}(I)$.

Comment: Yes I know this. I am asking why is $C_{c}^{\infty}(I)$ not dense in $W^{1,\,p}(I)$? What do we lose when we go from $C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ to $C_{c}^{\infty}(I)$ that makes us sacrifice density?

Comment: Just take any sequence in $\mathcal C_c^\infty (0,1)$ that converges to $f(x)=1\in W^{1,p}(0,1)$. The gradient will explose. (with a draw it's very easy to see).

Comment: I see what you are saying. But $C_{c}^{\infty}((0,1))$ is dense in $L^{p}((0,1))$. So if $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ in $L^{p}((0,1))$ and likewise since $(f_{n}')\in C_{c}((0,1))$ then $f_{n}'\rightarrow f'$ in $L^{p}((0,1))$ wont we have that $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ in the $W^{1,\,p}$ norm?

Comment: The thing is in $W^{1,p}(0,1)$ you cannot define a function on the boundary as you want. In $W^{1,p}(0,1)$, the function $f(x)=1$ must have $f(0)=f(1)=1$. You'll find more information with the [trace operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_operator)

Comment: I agree. I am clearly not understand something properly here. I think I may have identified what I am mistaken about. Please clarify for me. We can show that a function $f$ belongs to $L^{p}$ simply by showing $\|f\|_{p}<\infty$. However, I have been thinking that it is sufficient to show $f$ belongs to $W^{1,\,p}$ if $\|f\|_{W^{1,\,p}}<\infty$. This is incorrect, that is, $\|f\|_{W^{1,\,p}}\nRightarrow f\in W^{1,\,p}$

Comment: you are completely right. The main difference between $W^{1,p}(I)$ and $L^p(I)$, it's on $W^{1,p}(I)$ you cannot define the function on the boundary as you want (in contrary to $L^p(I)$ as far as the boundary has measure $0$). For example, if you consider $f(x)=1$ in $L^p(0,1)$, you rather consider $f$ as $f(x)=1$ a.e. If you consider it as a $W^{1,p}(0,1)$ function, you also consider it as $f(x)=1$ a.e. except at the boundary. i.e. as a $W^{1,p}(0,1)$ function, $f(0)=f(1)=1$. And the reason come from the continuity of the trace operator.

Comment: Maybe something can help you to understand : $\mathcal C^1\left(\bar I\right)$ is dense in $W^{1,p}(I)$. And this force you to define a function $f\in W^{1,p}(I)$ uniquely on the boundary of $I$.

Comment: I think I have the hang of it. Please tell me if my reasoning here is correct. Suppose $u\in W^{1,\,p}(I)$ then $\exists g\in L^{p}(I)$ such that $u'=g$. Clearly $u\in L^{p}(I)$ so $\exists (u_{n})\in C^{1}_{c}(I)$ such that $u_{n}\rightarrow u$ in $L^{p}(I)$. However, we are not guaranteed that $u_{n}'\rightarrow g$ in $L^{p}(I)$ (with the obvious example being choose $u(x)=1\in W^{1,\,p}(I)$). So in general for $(u_{n})\in C_{c}^{1}(I)$, $\|u_{n}-u\|_{W^{1,\,p}}=\|u_{n}-u\|_{p}+\|u_{n}'-g\|_{p}\nrightarrow 0$.

Comment: For sure $u_n\not\to u$ in $W^{1,p}$ if $u\notin W_0^{1,p}(I)$ for the reason you said. But what you'll have it's a sequence $(u_n)$ in $\mathcal C^1(\bar I)$ s.t. $u_n\to u$ in $W^{1,p}(I)$.